# launchAgent getting SIGTERM too early for loginWindow user

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, launchd

Hi My OSX app has one launchAgent.

I have seen some scenario (1 out of 4 time) in which 
when I switch to loginWindow, it launches the launchAgent for loginWindow session, but this very soon receives the SIGTERM , within 3 seconds.

In other cases 3 out of 4 times it works fine.

Whenever this problem happens the observation is that while I am on loginWindow
three sessions get created and for each session all these three launchagent are getting created. weird .

Any clue what could cause this?

Comment: Anything in the system logs (see `Console.app`) about why the system is terminating your agent?

Comment: Nope. Nothing there already checked in console.app inside /Library/Logs/MyApp/